# How to make a plugin out of a .click() function

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How is it possible to create a plugin using this code as an example:

html:

```
 <div id="instance1">
   <a href="#">Click</a>
   <b>Change me</b>
 </div>
```

js:

```
$("#instance1 a").click(function(){
   $("#instance1 b").text('Changed');
   return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GSjWw/

I would want the initialization to be something like this:

```
 $("#instance1").newPlugin();
```

Which binds the `instance1` id to the click function, how would i update the Javascript code above.. Currently it selects first `#instance1`, but how does this change based on binding a new plugin?

Comment: Have you read the [jQuery docs on authoring plugins](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Getting_Started)? They answer your question succinctly and completely.

Comment: Looks clear, but real quick, how do i use `$(this a)` ?  would it be `$(this).child('a')`?

Comment: use class instead of ID and there are all sorts of ways to associate elements to each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.newPlugin = function() {
        var $this = this;
        return $this.each(function(){
            $this.find('a').click(function() {
                $this.find('b').text('Changed');
                return false;                                
            });
        });              
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the tutorial to create jquery plugin.

http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery_plugin/